# How to optimise join on 27m rows table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a table called follow that has 2 collumns user1_id, user2_id
where user1 follows user2. If user1 follows user2 and user2 follows user1 they are friends. I have to find the friends and store them in a table, but I would like to accomplish that in a convenient time because I've got 27m rows. I tried

```
create temporary table friends as (
select f1.* 
from follow f1 inner join follow f2
on f1.user1_id = f2.user2_id and f1.user2_id = f2.user1_id)
```

and

```
create temporary table friends as (
select user1_id, user2_id
from follow
where (user2_id, user1_id) in (select * from follow))
```

but they take too much time. Is there anything to improve the performance of this action? Can you suggest a better query for this example?

Comment: personally i would look at using http://openquery.com.au/node/23

Comment: The long execution time is a problem because, why? You don't have to do the creation multiple times do you? You can easily keep the created table synced with triggers, which will make inserts marginally slower.

Comment: there will be no inserts, it's a dataset for my university project and I have to make some aggregations(sums) based on that friendship. Having the friends dataset cached will make my queries way faster.

Comment: Did you think of usink a simple trigger that runs after every insertion to chek if they are freinds : after insert on follow if(usesr2 follow user1)  then insert into freinds user1 user2 like this you dont have to wait the sql it will run automatecly you just fetch the freinds table

Comment: Do you have any indexes? How many matching rows are you expecting?

Comment: i used bulk insertion because multivalue insertion in batches was really slow. I tried adding indexes on user ids and they already had.

Comment: Do you have a covering index for both user1_id and user2_id?

Comment: i think yes, mysql added it automatically

Comment: It is highly unlikely it would add a covering index (ie, and index that covers 2 columns) automatically. Can you post the table declare of the follow table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest two approaches.  The first uses `group by`:

```
create table friends as
      select least(user1_id, user2_id) as user1_id, greatest(user1_id, user2_id) as user2_id
      from follow
      group by least(user1_id, user2_id), greatest(user1_id, user2_id)
      having count(*) > 1;
```

This incurs the cost of the `group by` which is expensive, but may be a good option.

The other is to create an index on `follow(user1_id, user2_id)` and do:

```
create table friends as
    select user1_id, user2_id
    from follow f
    where user1_id < user2_id and
          exists (select 1
                  from follow f2
                  where f2.user1_id = f.user2_id and f2.user2_id = f.user1_id
                 );
```

This incurs an index lookup for many of the records in the table, but this may be the best option.

Comment: I tried the first and it took nice time. But to know I want each user's friends, so I have to remove the `user1_id < user2_id and`